# UIColor is there any one can tell me how i will code

Tags: swift, methods, arguments, uicolor, theos

Argument with uicolorlike this photo

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the Target Class is : CNContactView
and the Target Method is : -(void) setBackgroundColor:(id)

You can replace (id) with any value you need .. In your case (UIColor *) then add "arg" so it's gonna be (UIColor *)arg

In your Tweak.x it should be like this :

```
 %hook CNContactView
 -(void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)arg {

       // You can use this one
          arg = [UIColor redColor];


      // Or this one
         arg = [UIColor colorWithRed:36.0f/255.0f green:52.0f/255.0f blue:71.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];


       return %orig;

}

 %end
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.